# Updating state within setTimeout (React & React-Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What I've been trying to achieve are to update `state` and to update the same state again, based on Javascript's timer.

The reason why I can't achieve this seems to be the nature of `state` in React.js.

Here is a snippet of my experimentation...

```
render() {
    if (this.props.hasError) {
        setTimeout(function(){this.setState({showWarning: true}); }.bind(this), 3000);
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <Blah warning={this.state.showWarning} />
      </View>
    );
}
```

So, the objective is to change state for `only just a few seconds if there is a specific props provided`.

This approach seems to hit the limit of updating states, if `this.props.hasError` gets updated too frequently.

Apologies if this question is too basic.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @JosanIracheta There are two purposes. One is to change the background color of this component for 3 seconds, the other is to show a message, which is located in `<Blah />` (again, for 3 seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using function inside timeout this will change its scope use arow function

btw i have modify your code accordingly

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.hasError != this.props.hasError){
        this.setState({
            showWarning:nextProps.hasError 
        });
        setTimeout(()=> {
            this.setState({
                showWarning:!this.props.showWarning
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
}


render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.showWarning?<Blah warning={this.state.showWarning} />:null}
      </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't update your state in render() function. If you do so, you will end up in an infinite loop, that's why you got that error. You need to use:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (this.nextProps.hasError) {
        setTimeout(function(){this.setState({showWarning: true}); }.bind(this), 3000);
    }
}
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> There are two purposes. One is to change the background color of this
>   component for 3 seconds, the other is to show a message, which is
>   located in  (again, for 3 seconds)

Since you only want these changes to show for 3 seconds, you have to set them first, and then set the state to its opposite after 3 seconds using setTimeout.

Judging from your code, `this.props.hasError` is a boolean so we can set `showWarning` with that initially:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {showWarning: this.props.hasError}
}
```

When the component renders, it will show the current state and after 3 seconds, we will change the state:

```
componentDidMount(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({showWarning: false});
  }, 3000);
}
```